# Sending Joystick input to program using python

Tags: python, ubuntu, input, joystick, gamepad

I'm working with Ubuntu in vm and I want to send joystick inputs with Python script to other program.

Basically the same thing as https://pythonprogramming.net/direct-input-game-python-plays-gta-v/?completed=/open-cv-basics-python-plays-gta-v/ but with only joystick/gamepad.

:)

Comment: Do you have an example of what you've tried already?

Comment: I tried to find any "pyautogui-like libraries" for joysticks but found non.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to do the same thing but for a flight simulator and so far all i'm able to do is pick up physical joystick movement in python with the joystick module in pygame.

This is code taken from pygame documentation and it just displays the value of each axis of your joystick.

```
import pygame

# Define some colors.
BLACK = pygame.Color('black')
WHITE = pygame.Color('white')

# This is a simple class that will help us print to the screen.
# It has nothing to do with the joysticks, just outputting the
# information.
class TextPrint(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)

    def tprint(self, screen, textString):
        textBitmap = self.font.render(textString, True, BLACK)
        screen.blit(textBitmap, (self.x, self.y))
        self.y += self.line_height

    def reset(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 10
        self.line_height = 15

    def indent(self):
        self.x += 10

    def unindent(self):
        self.x -= 10


pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen (width, height).
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 200))
pygame.display.set_caption("AI fly")
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
# Used to manage how fast the screen updates.
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# Initialize the joysticks.
pygame.joystick.init()
# Get ready to print.
textPrint = TextPrint()

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close.
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop.
        elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print("Joystick button pressed.")
        elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
            print("Joystick button released.")

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    textPrint.reset()
    # Get count of joysticks.
    joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()

    # For each joystick:
    for i in range(joystick_count):
        joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(i)
        joystick.init()

        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Joystick {}".format(i))
        textPrint.indent()

        # for i in range(axes):
            # axis = joystick.get_axis(i)
            # textPrint.tprint(screen, "Axis {} value: {:>6.3f}".format(i, axis))
        # textPrint.unindent()

        axis0 = joystick.get_axis(0)

        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Axis {} value: {:>6.3f}".format(0, axis0))

        axis1 = joystick.get_axis(1)
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Axis {} value: {:>6.3f}".format(1, axis1))

        axis2 = joystick.get_axis(2)
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Axis {} value: {:>6.3f}".format(2, axis2))

        axis3 = joystick.get_axis(3)
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Axis {} value: {:>6.3f}".format(3, axis3))

    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT
    #
    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
    # Limit to 20 frames per second.
    clock.tick(20)
pygame.quit()
```